# When I try to add padding for columns the layout of responsiveness crashes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When I try to add `"padding:5px;"` for columns the layout of the responsive design crashes.

This is the HTML and CSS code and I commented on the padding for all of the classes that begin with "col-" and in this order, the layout works but when I pick up the comment the layout crashes.

This is the link to the code: https://codeshare.io/AdkwON

Comment: Please add your code (or a relevant part) to the question itself. A code formatting tool is supplied in the editor for this purpose.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You are having problems with the box-sizing, you should remove it from the body and attach it to a general selector like I've done above so it cascades to all other selectors properly.